# InvalidArgumentError when reading parquet files into Keras via Petastorm

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pyspark, databricks, petastorm

I'm trying to read in data from parquet for a language model.

The parquet contains two columns:

- target (int)
- feature_vec (int array)

I'm adapting the code from [this post](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/deep-learning/data-prep/petastorm.html) (Which works for me). When I try the code below I get an InvalidArgumentError when I try to run the model.

```
import random
from pyspark.sql import Row

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Embedding,  LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import  Sequence

from petastorm import make_batch_reader
from petastorm.etl.dataset_metadata import materialize_dataset
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

## build toy dataset
vocab_size = 250
seq_length = 100
parquet_path = '/dbfs/ml/langmod/petastorm/toy_dataset.parquet'

def row_generator(x):
    """Returns a single entry in the generated dataset. Return a bunch of random values as an example."""
    return Row(target = random.randint(0, vocab_size), feature_vec = [random.randint(0, vocab_size) for i in range(seq_length)])


rows_count = 1000
rows_rdd = sc.parallelize(range(rows_count)).map(row_generator)

df = spark.createDataFrame(rows_rdd)


df.write.parquet(parquet_path, mode = 'overwrite')


underscore_files = [f for f in os.listdir(get_local_path(parquet_path)) if f.startswith("_")]
pq.EXCLUDED_PARQUET_PATHS.update(underscore_files)
```

```
## build model and read in data from parquet, converting to tf.Dataset format

with make_batch_reader('file:/dbfs/' + parquet_path, num_epochs = None) as train_reader:
    train_dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(train_reader).map(lambda x: (tf.convert_to_tensor(x.feature_vec), tf.one_hot(x.target, depth = vocab_size)))   \
                                                        .apply(tf.data.experimental.unbatch())                                                            \
                                                        .batch(10, drop_remainder = True)


    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 20, mask_zero = True, input_length = None, name = 'embed'))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences = False, name = 'lstm1'))
    model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation = 'softmax', name = 'dense_layer'))
    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'])                                                         
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs = 2, steps_per_epoch = 10, verbose = 1)
```

Error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2202319388737190> in <module>
     10     model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation = 'softmax', name = 'dense_layer'))
     11     model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'])
---> 12     model.fit(train_dataset, epochs = 2, steps_per_epoch = 10, verbose = 1)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    725         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    726         workers=workers,
--> 727         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    728 
    729   def evaluate(self,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    673         validation_steps=validation_steps,
    674         validation_freq=validation_freq,
--> 675         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
    676 
    677   def evaluate(self,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    298           else:
    299             actual_inputs = ins()
--> 300           batch_outs = f(actual_inputs)
    301         except errors.OutOfRangeError:
    302           if is_dataset:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3474 
   3475     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3476                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3477     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3478     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1470         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1471                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1472                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1473         if run_metadata:
   1474           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of size 3
     [[{{node lstm1_3/transpose}}]]
     [[lstm1_3/TensorArrayUnstack_1/range/_459]]
  (1) Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of size 3
     [[{{node lstm1_3/transpose}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

This error is surprising since it seems to say there is a problem with the shape of the middle layer of the model, which should just fit the shape of the output of the previous layer.

However, if I convert the dataset to an iterator and then run the output X and Ys separately, it runs as expected for that batch:

```
with make_batch_reader('file:/dbfs/' + parquet_path, num_epochs = None) as train_reader:
  train_dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(train_reader).map(lambda x: (tf.convert_to_tensor(x.feature_vec), tf.one_hot(x.target, depth = vocab_size)))   \
                                                        .apply(tf.data.experimental.unbatch())                                                            \
                                                        .batch(10, drop_remainder = True)
  iterator = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  tensor = iterator.get_next()

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    features, target = sess.run(tensor)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 20, mask_zero = True, input_length = None, name = 'embed'))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences = False, name = 'lstm1'))
    model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation = 'softmax', name = 'dense_layer'))
    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'])                                                         

    model.fit(x = features, y = target,  verbose = 1)
```

```
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 76ms/sample - loss: 5.5202 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1000
```

I guess there is some issue with the way the integer array column is getting read in and converted to tf.Dataset format, but can't see what might be causing this. I assume there must be some issue with this line from the above block:

```
train_dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(train_reader).map(lambda x: (tf.convert_to_tensor(x.feature_vec), tf.one_hot(x.target, depth = vocab_size)))   \
                                                        .apply(tf.data.experimental.unbatch())                                                            \
                                                        .batch(10, drop_remainder = True)
```

I'm running databricks runtime ML 6.2

- tensorflow 1.15.0
- petastorm 0.8.0